# How to format data in Model before saving in Mongoose (ExpressJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I get Date from user in the string format and I currently convert into a Date in controller before creating the Schema object and saving. Is there a way to move this logic to model as it seems to me that Model is the right place for this

```
var RunSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    starttime: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});
```

Currently I do this

```
//req.body = {starttime;'2.05.2013 11:23:22'}
var run = new Run(req.body);
// util.getDate(datetime) returns false if invalid and Date() if valid
// req.body.starttime = '2.05.2013 11:23:22';
run.starttime = util.getDate(req.body.starttime);
run.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
    } else {
    }
});
```

On a sidenote, how do I assert if I want to process the param in custom function checks. Something like

```
    req.assert('name', 'Name can\'t be empty').len(1, 1000);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I'm not sure about the meaning of `req.body.starttime`, I'm pretty sure you're looking for the Schema objects `pre()` function which is part of the [Mongoose Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) and allows the definition of callback functions to be executed before data is saved. Probably something like this does the desired job:

```
var RunSchema = new Schema({
  [...]
  starttime: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

RunSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.starttime = new Date();
  next();
});
```

Note that the callback function for the `save` event is called every time before a record is created or updated. So this is for example the way for explicitly setting a "modified" timestamp.

EDIT:

Thanks to your comment, I now got a better understanding of what you want to achieve. In case you want to modify data before it gets assigned and persisted to the record, you can easily utilize the `set` property of the Schema:

```
// defining set within the schema
var RunSchema = new Schema({
  [...]
  starttime: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    set: util.getDate
  }
});
```

Assuming that the object `util` is within scope (required or whatever) your current implementation fits the signature for the property `set`:

```
function set(val, schemaType)
```

The optional parameter `schemaType` allows you to inspect the properties of your schema field definition if the transform process depends on it in any way.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am looking something on that lines but how does the pre function have access to the value '2.05.2013 11:23:22'?