# MongoDB/Mongoose saves Numbers as Doubles?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save millisecond date/time as a Number in mongodb, and it keeps showing as a `double` in mongo. How do I save it as a number without the `decimal`?

```
router.route('/reminders')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var reminder = new Reminder();
        reminder.datetime = req.body.datetime;    

        console.log(typeof req.body.datetime) // gives the right datetime milliseconds
        reminder.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'Reminder Created!'});
        })
    })
```

Comment: what value do you see in mongo and what value you see coming from the console.log?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512683/how-to-format-data-in-model-before-saving-in-mongoose-expressjs about formatting the date before saving it?

Comment: @GuyS this looks interesting, but I don't want to save as a Date, I want to save milliseconds as a Number.

Comment: @GuyS http://i.imgur.com/5XcpAQZ.png

Answer (score 0):

You could either use validation or setter function. Validation can be seen here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html where you could specify a regex. Using a setter function would also be good if you want to round of the decimal. Look at this article https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/f437FCPsVLY

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, Mongoose stores large integer values as doubles by default. To store them as 64-bit integers instead, you need to use the [`mongoose-long`](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-long) plug-in.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

var reminderSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    datetime: SchemaTypes.Long
});
```